# Browser doesn't render Font Awesome HTML entity if it is coming from javascript

Tags: reactjs, unicode, font-awesome, styled-components, html-entities

I'm using React and I'm getting a Font Awesome Unicode coming from an API response as a string `"f445"`.

I'm trying to render the Font Awesome dynamically, so I'm assigning the Unicode to a `data-icon` attribute to my HTML `<i>` tag like this ...

```
<i data-icon={`&#x${item.content.icon};`}></i>
```

And in the CSS I'm doing this ...

```
i {
    &:before {
        content: attr(data-icon);
        font-family: "Font-Awesome";
    }
}
```

However, that doesn't work and the browser renders it like this `&#xf5d3;`, but if I sent the code as a static string in the `data-icon` it works just fine and the icon renders in the browser ...

`<i data-icon="&#xf5d3;"></i>`

How can I solve this?